# Returning custom input data from PayPal

Tags: php, variables, return, paypal

I created a basic purchase script where a user enters their desired username and password, then they can purchase the membership on my website. But, when it goes to the return page, the values Username and Password don't show in the url. Here is the code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="CKQH4CYEMYLWW">
    <center>
        <span id="msgbox" style="display:none;"></span>
        <br><br>

        <input type="text" id="rusername" name="rusername" placeholder="Desired Username" class="usernamelogin">
        <br><br>

        <input type="password" id="rpassword" name="rpassword" placeholder="Desired Password" class="passwordlogin">
        <br><br>

        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: +1 to visit stackoverflow for the solution . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `cookie` variable for each `input` variable and pass the data accordingly . . and on return from *paypal* you can simply check the `cookie` variable and pass the data in the individual `input` accordingly ..

Comment: setcookie($_POST['username'], TRUE, time()+(3600 * 24));
setcookie($_POST['password'], TRUE, time()+(3600 * 24));

Does that seem about right?

Comment: if you are using php, then why not go for session variable . . it's more convenient to use session rather than cookie . . check manual for session http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php and for cookie http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: This is the correct syntax
`setcookie(<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>, TRUE, time()+(3600 * 24)); setcookie(<?php echo $_POST['password']; ?>, TRUE, time()+(3600 * 24));`

Answer (score 0):

Paypal Standard gives one variable 'custom' for passing custom data

so you can have a way to pass those values using this variable and getting back.

eg. you can seperate the values using | and get back

```
<input type="hidden" id="custom" name="custom" value="username|password"/>
```

you can set the values when your form is going to be submitted

when success page comes you can get the values

```
list($username,$password) = explode('|',$_POST['custom']);
```